# How to upload files with asp-classic

Tags: asp-classic

I want to create a page with asp-classic where users can upload files or zipped folders.

I've searched in Google but every solution I have found uses a third-party file. 
 But I haven't been able to get those files to work.

Comment: You can find lots of free scripts using pure ASP by searching "pure ASP upload" in a search engine..

Answer (score 33, accepted):

long time since I've done that but we used an upload without third party components, just two vbscript classes (solution credit goes to Lewis Moten).
It looks like you can still find this "Lewis Moten solution" in the wild

If you include the clsUpload file, further upload process is as simple as:

```vb
Dim objUpload 
Dim strFile, strPath
' Instantiate Upload Class '
Set objUpload = New clsUpload
strFile = objUpload.Fields("file").FileName
strPath = server.mappath("/data") & "/" & strFile
' Save the binary data to the file system '
objUpload("file").SaveAs strPath
Set objUpload = Nothing
```

That's all for the server-side...

On the client-side you just need your File input

```
<form name="Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="clsUpload.asp">
<div>Upload file: </div>
<div><INPUT TYPE="file" NAME="file"  > 
<input type="button" name="FileUpload" value="Upload File">    </div>
</form>
```

Hope this helps..

***Edit 23 June 2014***
As pointed out by Dave Wut my reference to the solution "in the wild" was not completely consistent with the code snippet provided. Hereby the full classes that I had used historically (comments trimmed to stay below the 30000 SO limit). It was an early version of the Lewis Moten solution found at http://planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=8525&lngWId=4

1) Contents of ***clsUpload.asp***

```vb
<!--METADATA
  TYPE="TypeLib"
  NAME="Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 Library"
  UUID="{00000205-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}"
  VERSION="2.5"
-->
<!--#INCLUDE FILE="clsField.asp"-->

<%
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'   Author:     Lewis Moten
'   Date:       March 19, 2002
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

' Upload class retrieves multi-part form data posted to web page
' and parses it into objects that are easy to interface with.
' Requires MDAC (ADODB) COM components found on most servers today
' Additional compenents are not necessary.
'

Class clsUpload
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Private mbinData            ' bytes visitor sent to server
    Private mlngChunkIndex      ' byte where next chunk starts
    Private mlngBytesReceived   ' length of data
    Private mstrDelimiter       ' Delimiter between multipart/form-data (43 chars)

    Private CR                  ' ANSI Carriage Return
    Private LF                  ' ANSI Line Feed
    Private CRLF                ' ANSI Carriage Return & Line Feed

    Private mobjFieldAry()      ' Array to hold field objects
    Private mlngCount           ' Number of fields parsed

' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Private Sub RequestData

        Dim llngLength      ' Number of bytes received

        ' Determine number bytes visitor sent
        mlngBytesReceived = Request.TotalBytes

        ' Store bytes recieved from visitor
        mbinData = Request.BinaryRead(mlngBytesReceived)

    End Sub
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Private Sub ParseDelimiter()

        ' Delimiter seperates multiple pieces of form data
            ' "around" 43 characters in length
            ' next character afterwards is carriage return (except last line has two --)
            ' first part of delmiter is dashes followed by hex number
            ' hex number is possibly the browsers session id?

        ' Examples:

        ' -----------------------------7d230d1f940246
        ' -----------------------------7d22ee291ae0114

        mstrDelimiter = MidB(mbinData, 1, InStrB(1, mbinData, CRLF) - 1)

    End Sub
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Private Sub ParseData()

        ' This procedure loops through each section (chunk) found within the
        ' delimiters and sends them to the parse chunk routine

        Dim llngStart   ' start position of chunk data
        Dim llngLength  ' Length of chunk
        Dim llngEnd     ' Last position of chunk data
        Dim lbinChunk   ' Binary contents of chunk

        ' Initialize at first character
        llngStart = 1

        ' Find start position
        llngStart = InStrB(llngStart, mbinData, mstrDelimiter & CRLF)

        ' While the start posotion was found
        While Not llngStart = 0

            ' Find the end position (after the start position)
            llngEnd = InStrB(llngStart + 1, mbinData, mstrDelimiter) - 2

            ' Determine Length of chunk
            llngLength = llngEnd - llngStart

            ' Pull out the chunk
            lbinChunk = MidB(mbinData, llngStart, llngLength)

            ' Parse the chunk
            Call ParseChunk(lbinChunk)

            ' Look for next chunk after the start position
            llngStart = InStrB(llngStart + 1, mbinData, mstrDelimiter & CRLF)

        Wend

    End Sub
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Private Sub ParseChunk(ByRef pbinChunk)

        ' This procedure gets a chunk passed to it and parses its contents.
        ' There is a general format that the chunk follows.

        ' First, the deliminator appears

        ' Next, headers are listed on each line that define properties of the chunk.

        '   Content-Disposition: form-data: name="File1"; filename="C:\Photo.gif"
        '   Content-Type: image/gif

        ' After this, a blank line appears and is followed by the binary data.

        Dim lstrName            ' Name of field
        Dim lstrFileName        ' File name of binary data
        Dim lstrContentType     ' Content type of binary data
        Dim lbinData            ' Binary data
        Dim lstrDisposition     ' Content Disposition
        Dim lstrValue           ' Value of field

        ' Parse out the content dispostion
        lstrDisposition = ParseDisposition(pbinChunk)

            ' And Parse the Name
            lstrName = ParseName(lstrDisposition)

            ' And the file name
            lstrFileName = ParseFileName(lstrDisposition)

        ' Parse out the Content Type
        lstrContentType = ParseContentType(pbinChunk)

        ' If the content type is not defined, then assume the
        ' field is a normal form field
        If lstrContentType = "" Then

            ' Parse Binary Data as Unicode
            lstrValue = CStrU(ParseBinaryData(pbinChunk))

        ' Else assume the field is binary data
        Else

            ' Parse Binary Data
            lbinData = ParseBinaryData(pbinChunk)

        End If

        ' Add a new field
        Call AddField(lstrName, lstrFileName, lstrContentType, lstrValue, lbinData)

    End Sub
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Private Sub AddField(ByRef pstrName, ByRef pstrFileName, ByRef pstrContentType, ByRef pstrValue, ByRef pbinData)

        Dim lobjField       ' Field object class

        ' Add a new index to the field array
        ' Make certain not to destroy current fields
        ReDim Preserve mobjFieldAry(mlngCount)

        ' Create new field object
        Set lobjField = New clsField

        ' Set field properties
        lobjField.Name = pstrName
        lobjField.FilePath = pstrFileName               
        lobjField.ContentType = pstrContentType

        ' If field is not a binary file
        If LenB(pbinData) = 0 Then

            lobjField.BinaryData = ChrB(0)
            lobjField.Value = pstrValue
            lobjField.Length = Len(pstrValue)

        ' Else field is a binary file
        Else

            lobjField.BinaryData = pbinData
            lobjField.Length = LenB(pbinData)
            lobjField.Value = ""

        End If

        ' Set field array index to new field
        Set mobjFieldAry(mlngCount) = lobjField

        ' Incriment field count
        mlngCount = mlngCount + 1

    End Sub
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Private Function ParseBinaryData(ByRef pbinChunk)

        ' Parses binary content of the chunk

        Dim llngStart   ' Start Position

        ' Find first occurence of a blank line
        llngStart = InStrB(1, pbinChunk, CRLF & CRLF)

        ' If it doesn't exist, then return nothing
        If llngStart = 0 Then Exit Function

        ' Incriment start to pass carriage returns and line feeds
        llngStart = llngStart + 4

        ' Return the last part of the chunk after the start position
        ParseBinaryData = MidB(pbinChunk, llngStart)

    End Function
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Private Function ParseContentType(ByRef pbinChunk)

        ' Parses the content type of a binary file.
        '   example: image/gif is the content type of a GIF image.

        Dim llngStart   ' Start Position
        Dim llngEnd     ' End Position
        Dim llngLength  ' Length

        ' Fid the first occurance of a line starting with Content-Type:
        llngStart = InStrB(1, pbinChunk, CRLF & CStrB("Content-Type:"), vbTextCompare)

        ' If not found, return nothing
        If llngStart = 0 Then Exit Function

        ' Find the end of the line
        llngEnd = InStrB(llngStart + 15, pbinChunk, CR)

        ' If not found, return nothing
        If llngEnd = 0 Then Exit Function

        ' Adjust start position to start after the text "Content-Type:"
        llngStart = llngStart + 15

        ' If the start position is the same or past the end, return nothing
        If llngStart >= llngEnd Then Exit Function

        ' Determine length
        llngLength = llngEnd - llngStart

        ' Pull out content type
        ' Convert to unicode
        ' Trim out whitespace
        ' Return results
        ParseContentType = Trim(CStrU(MidB(pbinChunk, llngStart, llngLength)))

    End Function
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Private Function ParseDisposition(ByRef pbinChunk)

        ' Parses the content-disposition from a chunk of data
        '
        ' Example:
        '
        '   Content-Disposition: form-data: name="File1"; filename="C:\Photo.gif"
        '
        '   Would Return:
        '       form-data: name="File1"; filename="C:\Photo.gif"

        Dim llngStart   ' Start Position
        Dim llngEnd     ' End Position
        Dim llngLength  ' Length

        ' Find first occurance of a line starting with Content-Disposition:
        llngStart = InStrB(1, pbinChunk, CRLF & CStrB("Content-Disposition:"), vbTextCompare)

        ' If not found, return nothing
        If llngStart = 0 Then Exit Function

        ' Find the end of the line
        llngEnd = InStrB(llngStart + 22, pbinChunk, CRLF)

        ' If not found, return nothing
        If llngEnd = 0 Then Exit Function

        ' Adjust start position to start after the text "Content-Disposition:"
        llngStart = llngStart + 22

        ' If the start position is the same or past the end, return nothing
        If llngStart >= llngEnd Then Exit Function

        ' Determine Length
        llngLength = llngEnd - llngStart

        ' Pull out content disposition
        ' Convert to Unicode
        ' Return Results
        ParseDisposition = CStrU(MidB(pbinChunk, llngStart, llngLength))

    End Function
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Private Function ParseName(ByRef pstrDisposition)

        ' Parses the name of the field from the content disposition
        '
        ' Example
        '
        '   form-data: name="File1"; filename="C:\Photo.gif"
        '
        '   Would Return:
        '       File1

        Dim llngStart   ' Start Position
        Dim llngEnd     ' End Position
        Dim llngLength  ' Length

        ' Find first occurance of text name="
        llngStart = InStr(1, pstrDisposition, "name=""", vbTextCompare)

        ' If not found, return nothing
        If llngStart = 0 Then Exit Function

        ' Find the closing quote
        llngEnd = InStr(llngStart + 6, pstrDisposition, """")

        ' If not found, return nothing
        If llngEnd = 0 Then Exit Function

        ' Adjust start position to start after the text name="
        llngStart = llngStart + 6

        ' If the start position is the same or past the end, return nothing
        If llngStart >= llngEnd Then Exit Function

        ' Determine Length
        llngLength = llngEnd - llngStart

        ' Pull out field name
        ' Return results
        ParseName = Mid(pstrDisposition, llngStart, llngLength)

    End Function
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Private Function ParseFileName(ByRef pstrDisposition)
        ' Parses the name of the field from the content disposition
        '
        ' Example
        '
        '   form-data: name="File1"; filename="C:\Photo.gif"
        '
        '   Would Return:
        '       C:\Photo.gif

        Dim llngStart   ' Start Position
        Dim llngEnd     ' End Position
        Dim llngLength  ' Length

        ' Find first occurance of text filename="
        llngStart = InStr(1, pstrDisposition, "filename=""", vbTextCompare)

        ' If not found, return nothing
        If llngStart = 0 Then Exit Function

        ' Find the closing quote
        llngEnd = InStr(llngStart + 10, pstrDisposition, """")

        ' If not found, return nothing
        If llngEnd = 0 Then Exit Function

        ' Adjust start position to start after the text filename="
        llngStart = llngStart + 10

        ' If the start position is the same of past the end, return nothing
        If llngStart >= llngEnd Then Exit Function

        ' Determine length
        llngLength = llngEnd - llngStart

        ' Pull out file name
        ' Return results
        ParseFileName = Mid(pstrDisposition, llngStart, llngLength)

    End Function
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Public Property Get Count()

        ' Return number of fields found
        Count = mlngCount

    End Property
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Public Default Property Get Fields(ByVal pstrName)

        Dim llngIndex   ' Index of current field

        ' If a number was passed
        If IsNumeric(pstrName) Then

            llngIndex = CLng(pstrName)

            ' If programmer requested an invalid number
            If llngIndex > mlngCount - 1 Or llngIndex < 0 Then
                ' Raise an error
                Call Err.Raise(vbObjectError + 1, "clsUpload.asp", "Object does not exist within the ordinal reference.")
                Exit Property
            End If

            ' Return the field class for the index specified
            Set Fields = mobjFieldAry(pstrName)

        ' Else a field name was passed
        Else

            ' convert name to lowercase
            pstrName = LCase(pstrname)

            ' Loop through each field
            For llngIndex = 0 To mlngCount - 1

                ' If name matches current fields name in lowercase
                If LCase(mobjFieldAry(llngIndex).Name) = pstrName Then

                    ' Return Field Class
                    Set Fields = mobjFieldAry(llngIndex)
                    Exit Property

                End If

            Next

        End If

        ' If matches were not found, return an empty field
        Set Fields = New clsField

'       ' ERROR ON NonExistant:
'       ' If matches were not found, raise an error of a non-existent field
'       Call Err.Raise(vbObjectError + 1, "clsUpload.asp", "Object does not exist within the ordinal reference.")
'       Exit Property

    End Property
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Private Sub Class_Terminate()

        ' This event is called when you destroy the class.
        '
        ' Example:
        '   Set objUpload = Nothing
        '
        ' Example:
        '   Response.End
        '
        ' Example:
        '   Page finnishes executing ...

        Dim llngIndex   ' Current Field Index

        ' Loop through fields
        For llngIndex = 0 To mlngCount - 1

            ' Release field object
            Set mobjFieldAry(llngIndex) = Nothing

        Next

        ' Redimension array and remove all data within
        ReDim mobjFieldAry(-1)

    End Sub
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Private Sub Class_Initialize()

        ' This event is called when you instantiate the class.
        '
        ' Example:
        '   Set objUpload = New clsUpload

        ' Redimension array with nothing
        ReDim mobjFieldAry(-1)

        ' Compile ANSI equivilants of carriage returns and line feeds

        CR = ChrB(Asc(vbCr))    ' vbCr      Carriage Return
        LF = ChrB(Asc(vbLf))    ' vbLf      Line Feed
        CRLF = CR & LF          ' vbCrLf    Carriage Return & Line Feed

        ' Set field count to zero
        mlngCount = 0

        ' Request data
        Call RequestData

        ' Parse out the delimiter
        Call ParseDelimiter()

        ' Parse the data
        Call ParseData

    End Sub
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Private Function CStrU(ByRef pstrANSI)

        ' Converts an ANSI string to Unicode
        ' Best used for small strings

        Dim llngLength  ' Length of ANSI string
        Dim llngIndex   ' Current position

        ' determine length
        llngLength = LenB(pstrANSI)

        ' Loop through each character
        For llngIndex = 1 To llngLength

            ' Pull out ANSI character
            ' Get Ascii value of ANSI character
            ' Get Unicode Character from Ascii
            ' Append character to results
            CStrU = CStrU & Chr(AscB(MidB(pstrANSI, llngIndex, 1)))

        Next

    End Function
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Private Function CStrB(ByRef pstrUnicode)

        ' Converts a Unicode string to ANSI
        ' Best used for small strings

        Dim llngLength  ' Length of ANSI string
        Dim llngIndex   ' Current position

        ' determine length
        llngLength = Len(pstrUnicode)

        ' Loop through each character
        For llngIndex = 1 To llngLength

            ' Pull out Unicode character
            ' Get Ascii value of Unicode character
            ' Get ANSI Character from Ascii
            ' Append character to results
            CStrB = CStrB & ChrB(Asc(Mid(pstrUnicode, llngIndex, 1)))

        Next

    End Function
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
End Class
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%>
```

2) Contents of ***clsField.asp***

```vb
<%
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'   Author:     Lewis Moten
'   Date:       March 19, 2002
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

' Field class represents interface to data passed within one field
'
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Class clsField

    Public Name             ' Name of the field defined in form

    Private mstrPath        ' Full path to file on visitors computer
                            ' C:\Documents and Settings\lmoten\Desktop\Photo.gif

    Public FileDir          ' Directory that file existed in on visitors computer
                            ' C:\Documents and Settings\lmoten\Desktop

    Public FileExt          ' Extension of the file
                            ' GIF

    Public FileName         ' Name of the file
                            ' Photo.gif

    Public ContentType      ' Content / Mime type of file
                            ' image/gif

    Public Value            ' Unicode value of field (used for normail form fields - not files)

    Public BinaryData       ' Binary data passed with field (for files)

    Public Length           ' byte size of value or binary data

    Private mstrText        ' Text buffer 
                                ' If text format of binary data is requested more then
                                ' once, this value will be read to prevent extra processing

' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Public Property Get BLOB()
        BLOB = BinaryData
    End Property
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Public Function BinaryAsText()

        ' Binary As Text returns the unicode equivilant of the binary data.
        ' this is useful if you expect a visitor to upload a text file that
        ' you will need to work with.

        ' NOTICE:
        ' NULL values will prematurely terminate your Unicode string.
        ' NULLs are usually found within binary files more often then plain-text files.
        ' a simple way around this may consist of replacing null values with another character
        ' such as a space " "

        Dim lbinBytes
        Dim lobjRs

        ' Don't convert binary data that does not exist
        If Length = 0 Then Exit Function
        If LenB(BinaryData) = 0 Then Exit Function

        ' If we previously converted binary to text, return the buffered content
        If Not Len(mstrText) = 0 Then
            BinaryAsText = mstrText
            Exit Function
        End If

        ' Convert Integer Subtype Array to Byte Subtype Array
        lbinBytes = ASCII2Bytes(BinaryData)

        ' Convert Byte Subtype Array to Unicode String
        mstrText = Bytes2Unicode(lbinBytes)

        ' Return Unicode Text
        BinaryAsText = mstrText

    End Function
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Public Sub SaveAs(ByRef pstrFileName)

        Dim lobjStream
        Dim lobjRs
        Dim lbinBytes

        ' Don't save files that do not posess binary data
        If Length = 0 Then Exit Sub
        If LenB(BinaryData) = 0 Then Exit Sub

        ' Create magical objects from never never land
        Set lobjStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

        ' Let stream know we are working with binary data
        lobjStream.Type = adTypeBinary

        ' Open stream
        Call lobjStream.Open()

        ' Convert Integer Subtype Array to Byte Subtype Array
        lbinBytes = ASCII2Bytes(BinaryData)

        ' Write binary data to stream
        Call lobjStream.Write(lbinBytes)

        ' Save the binary data to file system
        '   Overwrites file if previously exists!
        Call lobjStream.SaveToFile(pstrFileName, adSaveCreateOverWrite)

        ' Close the stream object
        Call lobjStream.Close()

        ' Release objects
        Set lobjStream = Nothing

    End Sub
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Public Property Let FilePath(ByRef pstrPath)

        mstrPath = pstrPath

        ' Parse File Ext
        If Not InStrRev(pstrPath, ".") = 0 Then
            FileExt = Mid(pstrPath, InStrRev(pstrPath, ".") + 1)
            FileExt = UCase(FileExt)
        End If

        ' Parse File Name
        If Not InStrRev(pstrPath, "\") = 0 Then
            FileName = Mid(pstrPath, InStrRev(pstrPath, "\") + 1)
        End If

        ' Parse File Dir
        If Not InStrRev(pstrPath, "\") = 0 Then
            FileDir = Mid(pstrPath, 1, InStrRev(pstrPath, "\") - 1)
        End If

    End Property
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Public Property Get FilePath()
        FilePath = mstrPath
    End Property
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Private Function ASCII2Bytes(ByRef pbinBinaryData)

        Dim lobjRs
        Dim llngLength
        Dim lbinBuffer

        ' get number of bytes
        llngLength = LenB(pbinBinaryData)

        Set lobjRs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

        ' create field in an empty recordset to hold binary data
        Call lobjRs.Fields.Append("BinaryData", adLongVarBinary, llngLength)

        ' Open recordset
        Call lobjRs.Open()

        ' Add a new record to recordset
        Call lobjRs.AddNew()

        ' Populate field with binary data
        Call lobjRs.Fields("BinaryData").AppendChunk(pbinBinaryData & ChrB(0))

        ' Update / Convert Binary Data
            ' Although the data we have is binary - it has still been
            ' formatted as 4 bytes to represent each byte.  When we
            ' update the recordset, the Integer Subtype Array that we
            ' passed into the Recordset will be converted into a
            ' Byte Subtype Array
        Call lobjRs.Update()

        ' Request binary data and save to stream
        lbinBuffer = lobjRs.Fields("BinaryData").GetChunk(llngLength)

        ' Close recordset
        Call lobjRs.Close()

        ' Release recordset from memory
        Set lobjRs = Nothing

        ' Return Bytes
        ASCII2Bytes = lbinBuffer

    End Function
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Private Function Bytes2Unicode(ByRef pbinBytes)

        Dim lobjRs
        Dim llngLength
        Dim lstrBuffer

        llngLength = LenB(pbinBytes)

        Set lobjRs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

        ' Create field in an empty recordset to hold binary data
        Call lobjRs.Fields.Append("BinaryData", adLongVarChar, llngLength)

        ' Open Recordset
        Call lobjRs.Open()

        ' Add a new record to recordset
        Call lobjRs.AddNew()

        ' Populate field with binary data
        Call lobjRs.Fields("BinaryData").AppendChunk(pbinBytes)

        ' Update / Convert.
            ' Ensure bytes are proper subtype
        Call lobjRs.Update()

        ' Request unicode value of binary data
        lstrBuffer = lobjRs.Fields("BinaryData").Value

        ' Close recordset
        Call lobjRs.Close()

        ' Release recordset from memory
        Set lobjRs = Nothing

        ' Return Unicode
        Bytes2Unicode = lstrBuffer

    End Function

' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
End Class
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%>
```

Comment: @DaveWut yes, thanks for pointing out that flaw. The full upload solution from Lewis Moten is not just one class, but two classes and a reference to the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 Library.

Comment: In clsUpload's Fields property, there is a Exit Property statement missing directly after the link.

' Return the field class for the index specified
Set Fields = mobjFieldAry(pstrName)

This keeps you from accessing fields using the integer indexor as it is currently written.  The Set of Fields near the bottom of the accessor overwrites the return with a blank clsField object.

Comment: @JeffFischer I'll be d***** ! You are right, great catch. Never had an issue using this code though, since fields were always retrieved by name.

Comment: Yeah, kinda figured as much given the examples.  Thanks for the code though!  Very helpful to have a plug-n-play solution handy!  Gracias!

Comment: Hello. I've made multiple versions of this code over the years with major changes between each version. The latest is version 3 - which is listed appropriately in the response. Although the code is "in the wild", PSC is the original place that I've always put my source code. - on a side note, I no longer offer support on this code.

Comment: @Lewie: PSC appears to be down/gone, and the version here appears to be your 2.5.  Could you post v3 somewhere?

Comment: I have this solution working reliably on Windows Server 2008 R2. What I am trying to do is upload a file with this code via an ajax call. Has anyone seen an example of this? I may post a new question. I think my problem is that I don't know how to pass the data appropriately to instantiate the upload.

Comment: `strFile = objUpload.Fields("file").FileName` should be `strFile = objUpload.Fields("file").FilePath` with the currently posted version of `clsUpload.asp`

Comment: Im having to add upload feature to a legacy classic asp app. I have a question - where do I put the server side code? Im workin gin VS2019 - which is beyond challenging. I added the asp file with the client side code given above. But I cannot get teh 'View Code' option. Pl help! I hv added the clsUpload and clsField code as separate asp files to the project.

Answer (score 3):

Property FileName never set, I add this missing line in clsUpload.asp (between lines 157 and 158) in Private Sub AddField(...)

```
    lobjField.Name = pstrName
    lobjField.FilePath = pstrFileName   
    lobjField.FileName = Mid(pstrFileName, InStrRev(pstrFileName, "\") + 1) ' <= line added to set the file name
    lobjField.ContentType = pstrContentType
```

You also have to declare the constant below: 
 Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2

Comment: how is this an answer to the question?

Comment: every comments mentionned "Unfortunately this code example won't work as is."   the solution is to correct the missing line and every thing is OK. The question is "how to upload files with asp-classic" the solution is given   but there is just a missing code...

Comment: ah... well your answer should stand on its own, so you should edit it to have the whole solution.

Comment: Also need to declare Const adTypeBinary = 1

Comment: Also need to declare Const adLongVarBinary = 205

Answer (score -4):

Unfortunately, it won't be possible to setup an upload service without at least a little effort on using third party scripts AND making some adjustments to your server.

You may check however with your hosting provider a list of components already installed; most hosting services also maintain libraries/faq's/wiki's with almost ready examples of how to use those components. If there is none, there is still FreeAspUpload which is a DLL-free component so may be used on any Classic ASP server.

After determining which component/script you will use, you must also check for write permissions on the target upload folders. If you can't set the target folder with permission to write files, your uploads won't work. Check if the control panel of your hosting provider allow you to do that, or if you need to make a request for those changes.

Comment: Well after a 2 years, it is quite possible the site for FreeAspUpload went down. I'm not the developer though, but in the essence the answer is correct.

Comment: The site has indeed gone down, but you can still find it, and the zip on the internet archive - https://web.archive.org/web/20100830055938/http://www.freeaspupload.net/

Comment: Almost none of this is true. You do not require third party scripts to upload a file with Classic ASP. There is no such thing as "Classic ASP server." It has always been called IIS.

Comment: Wow, 6 years later you come with this helpful comment. What part of 'scripts' or 'dll-free' you misunderstood?

At that time and earlier, it was common for hosting services to provide server installed components such as Persits AspUpload to simplify this routine, hence checking with the hosting services which one was available. 

Really, really helpful insights you had.

Comment: The comment by John about the web.archive.og download location is correct and it worked for me after downloading. very easy to use.