# reading excel data into asp file using asp classic

Tags: asp-classic

Excel file that is present on the local machine need to be read into asp page where the data is to be displayed in a table, can you help me in this please. There are code snippets that i can find which explains reading data from the file when the file is present on the server.

Comment: Do have an "excel file" in binary format or in text format (csv)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to upload the Excel file to the server first.

Here is other question about ASP file upload: [how to upload  files with asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190305/how-to-upload-files-with-asp-classic)

Comment: Hi can you please give me a link to pass multiple data from an asp page to another asp page...

Comment: @risha.9177719594 what do you mean "pass multiple data"? see here how to upload a file with classic asp: http://www.freeaspupload.net/