# VB.Net: How to upload a file in a <input type="file" ... >

Tags: html, vb.net

I am trying to make a Windows Forms Program to automatically upload a file to website.
The website has a "Browse..." button from the  `input type="file">` tag, on which I `InvokeMember("click")` that triggers the file picker, but I am unable to interact with it.

I am not familiar with that control. I have tried with `SendKeys.Send("quotes.html") : SendKeys.Send(Chr(13))` , with no success at all. The `SendKeys.Send` commands are executed only after I manually close the file picker.

Does anyone have an idea how to choose a file in this `<input type="file">` control using VB.NET?

**Edit #1** /08.04.2015 13:00/:

The web service, where I upload the files is a 3rd party application, which I cannot modify. I just want to interact with it so that my application can automatically upload the file, by interacting with the pop-up, file upload form, which appears, but I do not know how to do that.

The part of my code for this procedure is:

```
For Each OneElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
 If OneElement.GetAttribute("type") = "file" Then
    If OneElement.GetAttribute("name") = "file[]" Then
'Clicking the "Browse" button of the input type="file"
      OneElement.InvokeMember("click")
      'MsgBox("Here#13")
'Trying to fill in the "FileName:" textbox of the popup form
      SendKeys.Send( _
            "strig with the file address - e.g.: C:\Folder\File.html")
'Trying to click the open button, which is in focus
      SendKeys.Send(Chr(13))
    End If
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

As mentiontioned above, the `SendKeys.Send` is executed only after the file upload pop-up is closed.

**Edit #2: SOLVED!**  /14.04.2015 21:00/:

The solution is to make a new thread like that:

```
...
Dim tr As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf SendK)
tr.Start()
OneElement.InvokeMember("click")
tr.Abort()
...
Private Sub SendK()
Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000) ' could be less
SendKeys.SendWait("C:\TheFilePath.html") 'the file address path
SendKeys.SendWait(Chr(13))
End Sub
```

For whoever whants to upgrade it, as it a raw solution:
1. May be the new thread can be associated with the onclick event of the button;

Comment: Did you try searching? Like [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp).

Comment: If your using `ASPX` there is a `FileUpload` control.

Comment: SendKeys.Send("quotes.html") - this isn't how SendKeys works.

Comment: @Mathemats , I thought that `SendKeys ` sends a string of characters to the active window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I was looking for is this:

```
...
Dim tr As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf SendK)
tr.Start()
OneElement.InvokeMember("click")
tr.Abort()
...
Private Sub SendK()
Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000) ' could be less
SendKeys.SendWait("C:\TheFilePath.html") 'the file address path
SendKeys.SendWait(Chr(13))
End Sub
```

By adding the new thread I am finally able to interact with the `input type="file">` form and I send a string with the address path of the file on my PC with the `SendKeys.SendWait("path as string")`.

Answer (score 1):

Its kind of the same over here: [how to upload  files with asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190305/how-to-upload-files-with-asp-classic)

So what you want to do is pretty easy. You set your html form like they did in the link OneFineDay provided.

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
<input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and then you set up your script. For example:

```
Dim objUpload 
Dim strFile, strPath
' Instantiate Upload Class '
Set objUpload = New clsUpload
strFile = objUpload.Fields("file").FileName
strPath = server.mappath("/data") & "/" & strFile
' Save the binary data to the file system '
objUpload("file").SaveAs strPath
Set objUpload = Nothing
```

Just play around with it a little and you'll get the hang of it.