# How to securely upload file in Edge or Chrome using Classic ASP without extensions or IE Mode

Tags: file-upload, asp-classic, adodb

I have a Classic ASP application that allows the user to upload a file which is then saved to a network location. The problem is that the current versions of Edge and Chrome have instituted security measures that now prevent the file upload to work correctly without using IE Mode (in Edge) or an extension (in Chrome) that bypass the modern browser security functionality. I am currently using the code as seen in [How to upload files with asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190305/how-to-upload-files-with-asp-classic), which does work, but only if I bypass the security by using IE Mode or the Chrome extension.

I need to modify the ASP page in some way to allow for file uploads. I have found some mention of using ADODB Stream objects but I am not sure how this would be implemented or if it would solve my problem.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: There's a ready made solution which has served me well called Free Asp Upload.  Basically it's a class file which you add as a server side include.  The link where it used to be is dead, but you can find it on the internet archive.  It does indeed use an ADODB stream, (NB your Lewis Moten class file does that too.)  It works for me on current versions of  Edge, Chrome and Firefox.  https://web.archive.org/web/20120420004633/http://www.freeaspupload.net/ .  Alternatively there are paid for third party components you could look at, like Persits ASP Upload.

Comment: If SSL is used to submit the upload, I don't see problem with any browser on our websites.